# Functions returns int instead of bool

Tags: php, function, int, boolean

I got a very simple function to check whether an email exists in the database or not. It should return either `true` or `false`, but it is returning `1` or `0`.

```
function isUniqueEmail($email){
    global $database;
    $user_email = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email LIMIT 1");
    $user_email->execute(array('email' => $email));
    return ($user_email->rowCount() === 0) ? true : false;
}
```

What could it be?

Comment: well first you can just `return $user_email->rowCount() === 0;` without the ternary operator.  Secondly, how are you printing it out?  try `var_dump`

Comment: @DataHerder Thanks! It works with `var_dump()`, I was using `print_r`. Shouldn't it also return bools? Well, guess I gotta read the manual. (also, didn't remember I didn't need ternary there, thanks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using print_r it will not print (bool) values as you would think.  It converts it to a number of 1 for true and even nothing for false.  To check that use `var_dump`.  So yes your function is returning a boolean, but to check the type and value of your variable, use `var_dump`.

Answer (score 1):

As DataHerder has already pointed out, the cause of your problem is most likely a boolean value being displayed as an integer when you echo it.
Here is an
[example of that](http://www.tehplayground.com/#Kl57AbeDT).

Comment: At the time I posted this comment, DataHerder had not yet posted his answer, instead I referred to his comment.